# Scaling compositor effects based on render resolution

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have various effects like film grain, blur and lens distortion in my compositor. But if I do quick 50% scale renders, the effects become too 'large'. So the blur is too blurry, for example. So what I need is for those effects to be relative to render resolution size. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click over the render resolution % (or whatever value you need), right click, copy as new driver

[image]

in compositor, add a value node, right click -> paste as new driver

[image]

Now you can do whatever you want with that value and calculate with it as you need it.

e.g.

[image]

This is just an example -> it makes no sense but this is how you do it.

Note: for blur i think you can just check "relative" to get what you want.

[image]

Comment: nice and simple :). didn't realize the resolution field can be used as a driver :))

Comment: Thanks! This has opened up many possibilities. I've added inverse math to alter lens distortion based on a focal length driver value. Wide lens = more distortion. Long lens = low distortion. This saves me manually fiddling in the compositor when switching or tweaking cameras.

Comment: Great! Glad you made it!